# PowerShell Error handling Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

For one reason or another I can't seem to get `Invoke-Command` to produce an error and go the `Catch` block of my code. I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I can't see it.

I know that the `Try` block is always executed until a Terminating error is found. By using the switch `-ErrorAction Stop`, I expect it to become a Terminating error when the server name doesn't exist and move on to the `Catch` block to report on this error. But it's not really doing that, it just launches the job with `Invoke-Command`on the non-existing server. And when not using the switch `-AsJob` the error is catched. I'm a bit confused on what the best way would be for error handling here..

```
$Server = "Wrong"

Try {
         if ($Server -eq "UNC") {
             Write-Host "Running Start-Job" -ForegroundColor Cyan
             Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "Foo Start-Job" } -Name DelFiles
         }
         else {
              Write-Host "Running Invoke-Command" -ForegroundColor Cyan        
              Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "Foo Invoke-Command" } -ComputerName "$Server" -AsJob -JobName DelFiles -ErrorAction Stop
         }  
     }
Catch {
    Write-Host "Error detected"
}
```

Thank you for your help guys, I learned a lot here on StackOverflow. Once I'm getting better at PowerShell I hope to be able to help others out to.

Comment: -AsJob is going to create a local background job that will maintain the connection to the remote server.  I think the error will actually be recorded there, not in the local session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @mjolinor said. The error will be caught in the job, so you will need `get-job` or `receive-job` to see if there was an error.

`get-job [id]` will display the job for you, and you can check the `state` to see if it failed or completed or is still running, and `receive-job [id]` will echo back anything that would have normally been printed to stdout

Here is a bit of a test scenario for you I did on my pc
This first one I did on a non-existant PC

```
PS C:\hht> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { echo "hey"} -ComputerName test-pc -AsJob
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
22     Job22           RemoteJob       Running       True            test-pc               echo "hey"              

PS C:\hht> Get-Job 22

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
22     Job22           RemoteJob       Failed        False           test-pc               echo "hey"

PS C:\hht> Receive-Job 22

[test-pc] Connecting to remote server test-pc failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using 
Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer test-pc. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more 
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (test-pc:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken
```

As you can see it failed, so you can catch this in your main script with something like:

```
if((get-job $id).state -eq "Failed")
{
    echo "There was an error running job on $server"
}
```

And here is an example that works:

```
PS C:\hht> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { echo "hey"} -ComputerName test2-pc -AsJob
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
24     Job22           RemoteJob       Running       True            test-pc               echo "hey"  

PS C:\hht> Get-Job 24

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
24     Job24           RemoteJob       Completed     False           test2-pc       echo "hey" 

PS C:\hht> Receive-Job 24
hey
```

As you can see this job completed successfully and running `receive-job` returns the output from that job that was run on the remote PC

So in your code, the try-catch block will only catch any errors on the local session, not from the script block run on the remote pc

Comment: Thank you harry sib, this was exactly what I've been looking for. A bit strange that the `Invoke-Command`doesn't generate an error when the client can't be found, but this is indeed due to the `-AsJob` switch.